# Outlook.com only syncs new email, not migrated email from Google apps account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, outlook.com

Given Google's recent anti consumer/startup policies (no activesync on new iOS devices,no new Google apps free tier) we have migrated our custom domain email from Google Apps (essentially gmail) to Live (domains.live.com, essentially outlook.com)

We enabled pop3 on the gmail end and added the gmail as "another send and receive" email with the corresponding pop3 settings with destination as the "inbox" folder at the outlook.com end . Older emails are now appearing at the outlook.com end but something peculiar is happening; none of these pop3 migrated emails, now in the inbox, appear on any active sync devices (eg iPhone5).

Do I need to configure something more at the outlook.com (really a custom domain) to make sure **every** email in the new inbox (and other folders) also shows up in the newly configured active sync device?

Comment: have you selected enable POP3 for all items from gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the iPhone defaults to "sync last 3 days" in the settings. And because the migration started from "oldest" to "newest", some of the newer email that would have fallen in that time windows didn't exist (migrating took 2 full days)